# Firebase Crashlytics not reporting crashes on new tracked app versions - New app versions are not present in the Filter -> Versions list

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

So I have been able to track crashes without too many issues so far, up until recently. I have released two versions of my app on the Play Store (in the open-testing track) and I know for a fact they have had crashes.

I have released 1.0-beta02 and 1.0-beta03 with version codes 16 and 17. The last available version in the list is 1.0-beta01 with version code 15 in Crashlytics filter.

[image]

The two most recent versions are not available.

Also, in Google Analytics, the two other versions are visible.

Could it be that there is a maximum of versions you can track at once in Crashlytics? If so, how can I delete old versions?

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics will drop versions after over one hundred are created. You can have older versions deleted by writing in to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: Alright, but I only have about 15 versions uploaded. I will try contacting Firebase Support though. Thanks

Comment: That should not be the issue then. Could you cause a test crash on that new version with debug mode enabled, and post the log output here? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable_debug_logging